# Java call the Scala' Object elements Error

Tags: java, scala

My Code as below:

```
 public static boolean createTopic(String topicname, String zkUrl, int sessionTimeout, int connectTimeout, int partitions, int replicationFactor){
    boolean result = false;
    ZkUtils zkUtil = ZkUtils.apply(zkUrl, connectTimeout, sessionTimeout, JaasUtils.isZkSecurityEnabled());
    RackAwareMode rackAwareMode = RackAwareMode.Enforced;

    if(AdminUtils.topicExists(zkUtil, topicname)){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        AdminUtils.createTopic(zkUtil,topicname,partitions,replicationFactor, null, null);

    }
    return result;
}
```

and the Scala code as below

```
object RackAwareMode {
   case object Disabled extends RackAwareMode
   case object Enforced extends RackAwareMode
   case object Safe extends RackAwareMode
}
sealed trait RackAwareMode
```

The Error arised at the line below:
RackAwareMode rackAwareMode = RackAwareMode.Enforced;

Any ideas for me?

Comment: The Error is "expression expected"

Comment: Add edits to your question not via comments.

Answer (score 0):

Use `RackAwareMode.Enforced$.MODULE$`instead. The reason is how Scala generate inner classes.

Comment: it  worked !  thank you!